# Query no longer works in MySQL 5

Tags: mysql, database, mysql5

```
SELECT xp.productid, xp.product, xc.classid, xiW.date, xco.optionid, xco.option_name, xiW.id, xiW.image_path, xiW.path_on_server
    FROM xcart_products xp
    INNER JOIN xcart_variants xv ON xp.productid = xv.productid
    INNER JOIN xcart_variant_items xvi ON xv.variantid = xvi.variantid
    INNER JOIN xcart_class_options xco ON xvi.optionid = xco.optionid
    INNER JOIN xcart_classes xc ON xco.classid = xc.classid AND xc.class = 'COLOR'
    LEFT JOIN xcart_images_W xiW ON xiW.id = xvi.variantid
    GROUP BY xco.optionid
    ORDER by xp.product ASC
```

I get errors stating: xp.productid isn't in GROUP BY

Then I add that and get xp.product isn't in GROUP BY

I add that and get xc.classid isn't in GROUP BY

I add that and go all the way down too -

```
SELECT xp.productid, xp.product, xc.classid, xiW.date, xco.optionid, xco.option_name, xiW.id, xiW.image_path, xiW.path_on_server
    FROM xcart_products xp
    INNER JOIN xcart_variants xv ON xp.productid = xv.productid
    INNER JOIN xcart_variant_items xvi ON xv.variantid = xvi.variantid
    INNER JOIN xcart_class_options xco ON xvi.optionid = xco.optionid
    INNER JOIN xcart_classes xc ON xco.classid = xc.classid AND xc.class = 'COLOR'
    LEFT JOIN xcart_images_W xiW ON xiW.id = xvi.variantid
    GROUP BY xco.optionid, xp.productid, xp.product, xc.classid, xiW.date, xco.option_name, xiW.id, xiW.image_path, xiW.path_on_server
    ORDER by xp.product ASC
```

This can't be correct is it? It does run but I suppose GROUP BY is handled a bit differently in MySQL 5 than 4 or perhaps my query was barely functional in four?

Comment: SQL standard requires all non-aggregated fields to be included into `GROUP BY` clause. Maybe MySQL finally decided to do it right?

Comment: You're going to majorly jack your results if you group by like this, and don't realize what exactly is going on. Why are you group by if there is no aggregation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you have enabled [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode

Just disable it and you can again be happy with this great mysql extension to `GROUP_BY`